# How to access object list elements in java?

Tags: java, list

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) list.get(i);
    l.add(Arrays.toString(row));
    System.out.println("Element " + i + l);
}
```

According the that code, output is like that

> [Air Bükreş, BU, BUR, groundops@airbucharest.ro, Doküman Paylaşımı, E-posta]

But I need like that seperately

> Air Bükreş
>
> BU
>
> BUR
>
> groundops@airbucharest.ro
>
> Doküman Paylaşımı
>
> E-posta

I want it without '[' and ']'

Comment: Then don't use `Arrays.toString()`. It will comma separate the array and add the [] characters.

Comment: Is this a `List<Object>` or `List<Object[]>`?

Comment: @tobias_k `Object[]` can be a `Object`

Comment: You can write a simple method that prints out `row` your way.

Comment: @tobias_k, better to say it `could be` declared as such for more readability.

Comment: @tobias_k I agreed, it should be, it is much cleaner,  but maybe there are some reason why op stuck Object[] in List<Object>, and we are so limited so we cant understand that

Comment: @aysegulP try to iterate through `row` in same way as you iterate trough `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a simple method instead of Arrays.toString(row), that prints out/returns your way

for Object[]

```
public String printRow(Object[] row) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object object : row) {
        System.out.println(object);
        s.append(object + "\n");
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class testo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    list.add("1");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");

    Iterator<Object> it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){

        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}
}
```

output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Output is [Ljava.lang.Object;@6fdb6262

Comment: No,my output is like this .try this code .although its same.

Answer (score 0):

You're question is very unclear, but I believe you are adding an entire array inside a single position of your ArrayList. You probably have `list.add(items)` somewhere, where items is an `Object[]` and this will not give any errors as that is also an Object and thus will fit as an item in your list. If you want to add them separately you could use `list.addAll(Arrays.asList(items))`

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me what you are trying to achieve in your code. However if you question is "how do I print out a list of strings each on a new line" then here are two answers:

```
list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

and

```
System.out.println(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```